# MonoTouch - running mdtool from Jenkins

Tags: c#, iphone, .net, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I downloaded the latest MonoTouch (4.0.4.1 and MonoDevelop 2.6 beta) to fix some issues we were having.

I was hoping that my build in Jenkins (using mdtool) would start working, but no luck.

mdtool gives this error (shortened):

```
2011-07-28 08:18:47.399 mdtool[14484:60f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x492260 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-07-28 08:18:47.401 mdtool[14484:60f] +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xa0bdd3ec
2011-07-28 08:18:47.401 mdtool[14484:60f] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3f02540 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

In the past this was related to code generation with the designer.

Is this a known issue being working on by Xamarin?  (I can open a bugzilla bug if needed)

PS: one thing else to mention, is we have deleted the designer.cs files for several of our views.  (This was a crude way to disable code generation at the time, we needed to manually setup our outlets, exports, etc.)

EDIT: posted to bugzilla [here](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=97).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the stable version of MonoDevelop, you are using an outdated preview, that was fixed in later betas.

Comment: My "check for updates" button says it's up to date.  But I agree my MonoDevelop says 2.6 Beta 1.  Where can I get a working version?

Comment: I had to get 2.6 Beta 3 off monodevelop.com.  Thanks, it works from Jenkins.